# Reading a text file and moving files from it to a directory

Tags: python, io, shutil

I have a directory of images. Some of these images must be stored in a text file like 'pic1.jpg'

I need to extract this filename, pick up the matching file from the current working directory and move it to a separate folder (under the cwd).

This is the code I have so far, but I cant get the shutil operations to work. What am I doing wrong?

Current directory C:\BE

Have to move a file(s) 1,jpg, 2,jpg etc from a textfile called "filelist.txt" to C:\BE\2014-03-25_02-49-11

```
import os, datetime
import shutil

src = os.getcwd()
global mydir
def filecreation(content, filename):

    mydir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    try:
        os.makedirs(mydir)

    except OSError, e:

        if e.errno != 17:
            raise # This was not a "directory exist" error..
    with open(os.path.join(mydir, filename), 'w') as d:
        d.writelines(content)

    #shutil.copyfile(src,mydir)

def main():

    filelist = "filelist.txt"
    with open(filelist) as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()
        #content = shutil.copyfile(src, mydir)
        print content
    print "Here we are"
    #list=['1.jpg','2.jpg']
    filecreation(content,"filelist.txt")


    print "lets try another method"
    with open('filelist.txt','w+') as list_f:
        for filename in list_f:
            with open(filename) as f:
                content = f.read()
                #content = shutil.move(src,mydir)
                #content = shutil.copyfile(src,mydir)
                #for line in f  
                print "method 2 is working so far"





if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: If you have encountered any exception, post the stacktrace in the question

Comment: I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked -

```
from shutil import  copy
f = open(r'C:\Users\B\Desktop\BE Project\K\filelist.txt', 'r')
for i in f.readlines():
    print i
    copy(i.strip(),r"E:\Images")    

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right track. I can see you have already tried the module `shutil`

You can try this function `shutil.move`